# Retrieve App Store ID after Sign In with Apple

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes

I'm working on a social media project where users can sign in with their different profiles on different platforms (Facebook, Twitter etc.)

Currently, the app hasn't got a sign in option via Apple. The thing I want to achieve is, after signing in with Apple, storing that respective user's `app store id(s)` (if there is any) to later make it possible to query (and show) the reviews made under user's particular applications.

I search through app store connect API documents, but cannot find any solid info. And, run into some outdated discussions, thus cannot be sure about the questions in my mind:

- Is it possible to retrieve an Apple User's app store ID(s) after make her signing in with Apple?
- If yes, what is the necessary endpoint to retrieve app store IDs?
- Lastly, I understand I also need to create an account on Apple for my app to make these sign in features possible on my app. Should I require to pay for my Apple account to make these kind of features (signin in, making API endpoint calls etc.) activated on my app?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. No, it is not possible to get the App Store id. The user may choose to share their email with you when they sign in, and that may be the same Apple ID the use in the store, but it may not. They may also choose to share an anonymous relay email with you. 2. You get the email as part of the token passed to you the first time the user signs in. 3.  Yes, you need a paid membership to publish an app and to use Sign In with Apple.

Comment: Even if the user does share the same email with you that they use with the App Store there is no api to obtain App Store reviews using an email.  This is deliberate on apples part to preserve privacy and discourage unethical behaviour such as rewarding users for positive reviews.

Comment: I understand. And, even if there is, I see that I can never be sure that the e-mail I get is the same with the one they use on the app store's side. Thank you for enlightments

Comment: Apple protects the privacy of its customers. There is no f***ing way they would give you a user’s Apple ID. And the email you get is most likely not the user’s email, but one owned by apple who passes emails on to the user.